# How exactly keyword 'params' work?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, parameters

The following code sample prints:

```
T
T[]
T[]
```

While first two lines are as expected, why compiler selected param array for a regular array?

```
public class A
{
    public void Print<T>(T t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T");
    }

    public void Print<T>(params T[] t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T[]");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Print("string");
        a.Print("string","string");
        a.Print(new string[] {"a","b"});
    }
}
```

Comment: You ask a lot of interesting questions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the hood

```
a.Print("string","string");
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
a.Print(new string[]{"string","string"});
```

EDIT: Like I said, the `params` keyword only automagically creates the array for you, you tell the compiler: either accept an array of `T` directly or use the X input params to construct that array.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm totally misunderstanding something here.  Can you elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: MSIL doesn't have a concept of the params keyword for parameters. So the C# compiler sees the params on the parameter and when is being called actually changes the arguments to be an array.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Your example didn't make sense at first, because you're looking at the second and not the last method call.  Now I get it.  Thanks.  =]

Comment: I think the question is why does the compiler not choose a.Print<string[]> the first method, what rule says the params method is a better fit.

Comment: Because when making the actual params method call, the variable-length parameter set will be translated to T[], and so it fits the T[] version more. Remember, arrays are its own Array class, while for the first version, string is a class, not Array class though.

Answer (score 5):

It addition to what others have said, the *params* keyword also causes a  ParamArrayAttribute to the generated for array parameter. So, this...

```
public void Print<T>(params T[] t) { }
```

Is generated by the compiler as...

```
public void Print<T>([ParamArray] T[] t); { }
```

It is that attribute which indicates to the compiler and the IDE that the method can be called using simpler syntax...

```
a.Print("string", "string");
```

rather than...

```
a.Print(new string[] { "string", "string" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Params allows you to pass multiple objects of the same type.  it is a shortcut way of passing array

Comment: As others write, there's no such thing as a params array, nor is there any 'mapping to  a params array'. It's just an array and params keyword allows for a writing a more compact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually has more to do with type inference than with the params keyword.  The inference engine assumes on the third line that the type of T is string[] and therefore passes it to the first method.

try Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)) if you don't believe me

Comment: nope, you're not getting what I'm saying.  The first the inference engine maps T to type string, the 3rd it maps T to type string[].  Just replace your console outputs with Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); and you'll see

Comment: @George, You're incorrect: T will be string in all three cases.

Comment: The second and third method calls are identical to the computer.  Syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

when having the params keyword, the compiler will do a little bit of translation for the formal function declaration, as well as the actual function call.

Formal function declaration:

Under the hood, the IL will be translated to essentially the same as

```
public void Print<T>(T[] array);
```

Except, when compiling, the *actual function call* will be checked for syntax translation. Meaning,

```
a.Print("string1", "string2");
```

Becomes the same IL code as

```
a.Print(new string[]{"string1", "string2"});
```

That is why line 2 and 3 are the same output, because under the hood, they got translated to the exact same IL.

Question about why line 3 is not print "T" is because, .NET compiler will always try to find the best overloaded match, and so both line 2 and 3 called to the T[] version instead of the plain T.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as arul said. If you open up the project in reflector, you'll see the following:

```
a.Print<string>(new string[] { "string", "string" });
```